# Simple example for aio_write()

Tags: c, asynchronous, io, posix, aio

I'm searching for a simple example for the `POSIX aio_write` function.

#### What I tried so far

*The below is not too important. Just jump to answer*

The code below creates a file, but does not write anything to it. aio_error returns `22` (= `quota exceeded`, but there is enough space and r/w-permission on the drive).

```
#include <aio.h>
#include <stdio.h>


char CONTENT[] = "asdf;";
const int LENGTH = 5;

struct aiocb createIoRequest(int fd,  
                            off_t offset, 
                            volatile void * content, 
                            size_t length){
    struct aiocb ret; // <-- not initialized. Will lead to an error ( see answer) 
    {
        ret.aio_fildes = fd;
        ret.aio_offset = offset;
        ret.aio_buf = content;
        ret.aio_nbytes = length;            
    }
    return ret;
}


int main(){

    FILE * file = fopen("outfile.txt","w");
    int fd = fileno(file);
    {    
        struct aiocb op  = createIoRequest(fd,0,CONTENT,LENGTH);        

        // schedule write
        // for valgrind mem leak output see comments from answer in
        //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248720/aio-h-aio-read-and-write-memory-leak
        int ret = aio_write(&op);
        printf("aio_write 1: %d\n",ret);

        // wait until everything is done
        {
            const struct aiocb * aiolist[1];
            aiolist[0] = &op;

            int ret = aio_suspend(aiolist,1,NULL);
            printf("aio_suspend: %d\n",ret);

            // report possible errors
            {
                ret = aio_error(&op);
                printf("errno 1: %d\n",ret);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: strongly suggest reading (aio_write)[https://software.intel.com/en-us/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference-example-for-aio-read-and-aio-write-functions]  which answers your question/request for an example

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE * file = fopen("outfile.txt","w");`  When calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  Similar considerations exist for all the C library functions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Checking you code with valgrind reports `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`

#### Problem with your code

The aiocb is not initialized.

## Examples

The examples below do not contain any "success"-checks (e.g. `file != NULL`, etc). This for the sake of readability. In productive code you should check the return values.

### Example1

The program below writed `asdf;` to `outfile.txt`. The aiocb struct is initialized inside `createIoRequest()`

```
#include <aio.h>
#include <stdio.h>


char CONTENT[] = "asdf;";
const int LENGTH = 5;

struct aiocb createIoRequest(int fd,  
                            off_t offset, 
                            volatile void * content, 
                            size_t length){
    // create and initialize the aiocb structure.
    // If we don't init to 0, we have undefined behavior.
    // E.g. through sigevent op.aio_sigevent there could be 
    //      a callback function being set, that the program
    //      tries to call - which will then fail.
    struct aiocb ret = {0};
    {
        ret.aio_fildes = fd;
        ret.aio_offset = offset;
        ret.aio_buf = content;
        ret.aio_nbytes = length;            
    }
    return ret;
}


int main(){

    FILE * file = fopen("outfile.txt","w");
    int fd = fileno(file);
    {    
        struct aiocb op  = createIoRequest(fd,0,CONTENT,LENGTH);        

        // schedule write
        // for valgrind mem leak output see comments from answer in
        //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248720/aio-h-aio-read-and-write-memory-leak
        int ret = aio_write(&op);
        printf("aio_write 1: %d\n",ret);

        // wait until everything is done
        {
            const struct aiocb * aiolist[1];
            aiolist[0] = &op;

            int ret = aio_suspend(aiolist,1,NULL);
            printf("aio_suspend: %d\n",ret);

            // report possible errors
            {
                ret = aio_error(&op);
                printf("errno 1: %d\n",ret);
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);


    return 0;
}
```

### Example2

The program below simply extends the one above to have two async writes to the file

```
#include <aio.h>
#include <stdio.h>


char CONTENT[] = "asdf;";
const int LENGTH = 5;

struct aiocb createIoRequest(int fd,  
                            off_t offset, 
                            volatile void * content, 
                            size_t length){
    // create and initialize the aiocb structure.
    // If we don't init to 0, we have undefined behavior.
    // E.g. through sigevent op.aio_sigevent there could be 
    //      a callback function being set, that the program
    //      tries to call - which will then fail.
    struct aiocb ret = {0};
    {
        ret.aio_fildes = fd;
        ret.aio_offset = offset;
        ret.aio_buf = content;
        ret.aio_nbytes = length;            
    }
    return ret;
}


int main(){

    FILE * file = fopen("outfile.txt","w");
    int fd = fileno(file);
    {    
        struct aiocb op  = createIoRequest(fd,0,CONTENT,LENGTH);
        struct aiocb op2 = createIoRequest(fd,LENGTH,CONTENT,LENGTH);

        // schedule write
        // for valgrind mem leak output see comments from answer in
        //   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248720/aio-h-aio-read-and-write-memory-leak
        int ret = aio_write(&op);
        printf("aio_write 1: %d\n",ret);
        ret = aio_write(&op2);
        printf("aio_write 2: %d\n",ret);        

        // wait until everything is done
        {
            const int OPs = 2;
            const struct aiocb * aiolist[OPs];
            aiolist[0] = &op;
            aiolist[1] = &op2;

            int ret = aio_suspend(aiolist,OPs,NULL);
            printf("aio_suspend: %d\n",ret);

            // report possible errors
            {
                ret = aio_error(&op);
                printf("errno 1: %d\n",ret);
                ret = aio_error(&op2);
                printf("errno 2: %d\n",ret);
                // error codes can be checked in <errno.h>
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is a good idea to zero out the control block buffer before use.
See the Notes section at https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/aio.7.html.